# VRTText was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, augmented-reality

I'm trying to create Augmented reality app with React Native I installed @viro-community/react-viro
and when Im trying to start the app it shows me this error

this is my code :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { ViroARScene, ViroText, ViroConstants,ViroARSceneNavigator } from '@viro-community/react-viro';


const InititalScene = () => {
  return (
  <ViroARScene>
    <ViroText text={"Hello team"} position={[0,0,-5]} />
  </ViroARScene>
  )
}

export default App = () => {
  return(
   
    <ViroARSceneNavigator 
    initialScene={{scene:InititalScene}}
    styles={{flex:1}}
    />
   
  )
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
})

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwYtZ.png)
```

It should shows me the camera with the title Hello team on the camera

Comment: check out demo. it is working perfectly